# Visual Studio 2012 Express: Selecting 'Debug' or 'Release' in solution configuration drop down doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, web-config, webdeploy

Visual Studio 2012 Express, MVC 4 App: Selecting 'Debug' or 'Release' in solution configuration drop down doesn't work.

I have Web.Release.Config & Web.Debug.Config. There is a transform

```
   <appSettings>
      <add key="Environment" value="Release" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
   </appSettings>
```

that changes this in web.config:

```
 <add key="Environment" value="DEVELOPMENT" />
```

to this in release mode (web.release.config)

```
 <add key="Environment" value="Release" />
```

I have previewed it by right clicking on Web.Release.Config and 'preview transform' - and it behaves as it should.

On a view I have the following:
@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"]

It always shows 'DEVELOPMENT' - it is never blank - regardless whether I select 'Debug' or 'Release' from the solution configuration drop down prior to clicking 'start without debugging'

[image: Debug or Release menu]

Shouldn't this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so, Microsoft thought it would be a good idea to not use your custom web.config files when running in debug mode on your local box. Those only get used when you publish.. I guess that's great when.... well, never....

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer does not really answer the question. It is more of a comment (and opinionated). Please read the FAQ. :)

Comment: Thx, really? That would be ridiculous. I've moved onto something else - will follow up on this soon.

Comment: Is there really no way to switch between Debug and Release when running locally? This sounds like an IDE bug to me.